# Why can't I access this json to php array?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get stock prices from this api using curl

```
//Initialize cURL.
$ch = curl_init();
 
//Set the URL that you want to GET by using the CURLOPT_URL option.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,msft&types=quote&filter=latestPrice&token=(redacted)');
 
//Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so that the content is returned as a variable.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
//Set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true to follow redirects.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 
//Execute the request.
$data = curl_exec($ch);
 
//Close the cURL handle.
curl_close($ch);
 
$stockdata = json_decode($data, true);
```

Right now I am getting this error: **Notice: Undefined offset: 0**

Here is the json I have converted into an array:

```
{"AAPL":{"quote":{"latestPrice":425.04}},"MSFT":{"quote":{"latestPrice":205.01}}}
```

Here is my code I am using to try and access the array, later I want to loop through all of the prices.

```
echo $stockdata[0]['quote']['latestPrice'];
```

Comment: `echo $stockdata['AAPL']['quote']['latestPrice'];` gives `425.04`.

Comment: I want to try and cycle through all of the quotes I get using a loop later

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Updated answer, when first key name is unknown.

Comment: Updated answer, lopping thru stocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an associated array, it is not numeric indexed anymore and you need to access its key by name which is 'AAPL'.

```
echo $stockdata['AAPL']['quote']['latestPrice'];
```

prints out

> 425.04

---

## Update 1

When you do not know the first key, just get it like this

```
echo $stockdata[array_keys($stockdata)[0]]['quote']['latestPrice'];
```

**Explanation**
`array_keys($stockdata)` will give you another array with all keynames as a numeric index based array. With `[0]` you access the first element (0th element) which is 'AAPL' in this example.

---

## Update 2

Based on comments for looping through, you could do it like this

```
foreach($stockdata as $stock => $data) {
    echo "{$stock} => {$data['quote']['latestPrice']}\n";
}
```

> AAPL => 425.04
> MSFT => 205.01

Comment: @IncredibleHat Did not see that comment during writing the anwer. Thanks for the hint. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Well, I actually meant `foreach($stockdata as $stock => $info) { .. }` so they can list out all the stock names with `$stock` and then access the info of it like `$info['quote']['latestPrice']`. Either way, its pretty easy to get at all the data from multiple angles, so its good to have multiple examples of such.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Ah, I see. Updated again.